# Delete columns before today's date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been struggling with this for a couple weeks now. I have [posted a question here a couple days a go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71842214/delete-columns-before-todays-date-and-add-new-columns-after-30-days) but still i didn't got and solution yet. Probably because in fact it was a 2-3 tasks question and not so well explained by my fault. Thus i decided to post another one with a one (of the 2-3) more simple task.

So, i have the script below which deletes in the sample sheet the columns dates before today's date. The script works fine but i have two issues.

First... If the number of the old dates/columns is one it works fine. It deletes only the day before and NOT the first 3 columns (A,B & C in the sample sheet) which i want to keep. If they are more the one old dates then the script deletes several columns/dates before and after today's date. What i want is to delete all the columns/dates ONLY before today's date and NOT the first 3 columns (A,B & C in the sample sheet) which i want to keep.

The second issue is kinda weird. Currently i am running the script from a custom menu ("My Tools" in the sample sheet). Now, when run the script from the custom menu or with the "Run" button in script editor it works. When i try to add a time-driven trigger (not programmatically. i don't know how) so to run it once every 24 hours, then i get a script error with this message: *Exception: Range not found at deleteColumnsDate(Code:14:49)*.

This is a sample of my working sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NJvcLxwc96411-Sl_aTu1d-J5gQvqlZjPUQbWZoRqBM/edit?usp=sharing

And this is the script that i am currently using:

```
function onOpen()
    {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('My Tools')
            .addItem('Delete Older Dates','deleteColumnsDate')
            .addToUi();
    }

  function deleteColumnsDate(row)
    {
      var row = (typeof(row) !== 'undefined') ? row : '3';
      var day = 86400000;
      var today = new Date().getTime();
      var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row + ':' + row);
      var rngA = rng.getValues();
      for(var i = 1; i < rngA[0].length ;i++)
    {
      if(isDate(rngA[0][i]) && (((today - new Date(rngA[0][i]).getTime())/day) > 1 ))
        {
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().deleteColumns(i + 1);
        }

      }
    }

    function isDate (x)  
    { 
      return (null != x) && !isNaN(x) && ("undefined" !== typeof x.getDate); 
    }
```

So, what am i doing wrong here?. Is it possible to make this process to run fully automatically every 24 hours?

Thank you in advance

Nessus

Comment: You can not have a parameter in the function because the trigger event object will populate it.

Comment: I believe Cooper is right.  A time based trigger passes an event object as the only parameter to the script.  It is not a row number.  So row is !== undefined and so it is object not a number.

Comment: Sorry guys but beside some basic stuff i am completely noob in script coding and therefore i have no idea what to do. Can you please be more specific coding wise?

Comment: @Cooper @TheWizEd Should i change something in this line?... `var row = (typeof(row) !== 'undefined') ? row : '3';`

Comment: If you wish to pass data to a function that is timebased triggered you could get the data from properties service or read it from a spreadsheet because there is no way to pass a parameter to it from the command line because the trigger will pass it's event object to the first parameter every time.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper... And how i can do that ?. Can you please be more specific to a noob like me?

Comment: Go lookup Properties Service in the Documentation and learn by doing.  I'm not suggesting that it will replace a parameter but it's a way to get data into your function on the next execution trigger.  It's not the same as a command line parameter though.  So maybe you can't do what you want.

Comment: Ha... ok. Thanks.

So you are telling me that this can work from a custom menu but it's not possible to work with any trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put a time trigger, you can't use getActiveSheet(). Instead you should use SpreadsheetApp.openById( [ID] )

You will find your ID inside URL of the document like : docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/***abc1234567***/edit#gid=0

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid

EDIT:

As Cooper mentionned it, I forgot something.
Try this way :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById( [SHEET ID] );
var sh = ss.getSheetByName( [SHEET NAME] ); //delete column here
var rng = sh.getRange(row + ':' + row);
```

Complete function:

```
  function deleteColumnsDate() {

    var day = 86400000;
    var today = new Date().getTime();

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(" [SHEET ID]");
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(" [SHEET NAME] ");
    var rng = sh.getRange('A1:Z1'); // change if you need larger
    var rngA = rng.getValues();

    var nb_to_delete = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < rngA[0].length ;i++) { // start colonne B
      if(isDate(rngA[0][i]) && (((today - new Date(rngA[0][i]).getTime())/day) > 1 )){
        nb_to_delete++;
      }
    }
    sh.deleteColumns(2, nb_to_delete);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Waxim but i am still geting the same error. This is the changed line in my script code... `var rng = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1NJvcLxwc96411-Sl_aTu1d-J5gQvqlZjPUQbWZoRqBM").getRange(row + ':' + row);`

Comment: Also changed this line to *SpreadsheetApp.openById*... `SpreadsheetApp.openById("1NJvcLxwc96411-Sl_aTu1d-J5gQvqlZjPUQbWZoRqBM").deleteColumns(i + 1);`

Still the same error.

Comment: getActiveSheet() and SpreadsheetApp.openById() are not the same thing.  The answer does not really make much sense.

Comment: Sorry @Waxim. Still getting the same error in this line: `var rng = sh.getRange(row + ':' + row);`. This is how my script looks like now... [link](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1yp1NUz2f2wzQwhvIUEgUaPaWxT3JYkJ_OMJ7dQ_qpNOkyQsfix9QmqBX/edit)

Comment: see the edit on my answer

Comment: @Waxim I've added your code and i am getting another error now: `isDate is not defined`. If i add the function from my script then i get the error: `Those columns are out of bounds at deleteColumnsDate(Code:17:8)`. In any case i am abbanding this project/task since it turns out it's extremely difficult to automate a such simple task as just to delete a couple of columns. Thank for your time and effort on this and let me know if it's ok to accept this as an answer.

Comment: I've edited only the main function, you still need isDate() function. The second error appears because of the range (A1:Z1) which is probably too large, you have to adapt it